# Different SimpleMessageListenerContainer implementations in same spring cloud aws example

Tags: amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

I Have two SQS queue listeners in my spring cloud aws application. How can i use different credentials to different queue listeners. i.e., i want to use the one credential configuration to queue1 and want to use the another credentials for queue2 in same application.
Can you please provide the solution to above scenario.